# Core Data Transformer

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, sqlite, core-data

I want to encrypt some Core Data columns with the `NSValueTransformer` class but I'm not quite sure what encryption method to use. Has anyone ever tried to encrypt individual entities while using Core Data and if so, is there any sample code of a working implementation? I would want the encryption to not interfere with any `NSPredicate`s I use later on to get back data from the db

Comment: What do you mean by _encryption_ in this context?

Comment: um i mean at the moment the sqlite db core data persists to is readable by anyone. I want each entry to be secured along the lines of a AES256 level encryption

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iPhoneCoreDataRecipes sample code from Apple has an example of using a subclass of `NSValueTransformer` along with a transformable attribute in the model.  See the transformable attribute type setting:

[image]

and the value transformer implementation:

In your case, you would need to provide the encryption and decryption algorithms in the `transformedValue` and `reverseTransformedValue` methods respectively, along the lines [suggest here](http://robnapier.net/blog/aes-commoncrypto-564).

Comment: I have attempted to do this but have had issues with getting my NSFetchedResultsController to get back results when i try to get back a sorted result set from a db query. it seems the transformer interferes with this. do you know why?

Comment: yes a regular fetch request gets me back an array of managed objects. but the NSFetchedResultsController does not get my back any results when i try to do a sort and a section by key path on the first name of any entry in an entity

Comment: Strange.  Sounds like a bug in the framework.  Are the methods of the `NSValueTransformer` ever called when using the `NSFetchedResultsController`?  Alternative encryption is encrypt the entire Core Data store, using one of the NSFileProtection attributes. The problem is that it requires the user have a passcode set on the device.

Comment: yes the methods are being called as confirmed by breakpoints. The NSFileProtection attributes are not good enough apparently and each db entry must be encrypted as per the requirements. I am really at a loss  because ive read others experiencing this issue but no resolution. This person has a similar issue here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12845831/nsfetchedresultscontroller-not-sorting-on-encrypted-attributes

Comment: is there a way to somehow sort/assign section labels on the nsfetchedresult controller after it gets back just the search results?